# Parsing and processing tabular .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm supposed to write a program that reads a file and then calculates the max and min and the average of the height and weight columns and adds an additional columnn that has the BMI calculated based on each height and weight. 
The file is formatted like so:

```
Name        Height(m)   Weight(kg)
Joe         1.82        72.57
Mary        1.60        63.50
Dion        1.90        90.71
Kayla       1.72        66.31
Jose        1.78        70.23
Sofia       1.63        65.12
Erik        1.98        92.21
Sara        1.57        65.77
```

The output should be as follows: 
[image: expected output]

I have the very very basics down (reading the text file). I know what I need to do next which is iterate through each column and add up all the data to get the average, etc etc. But I don't know how to code for it. You don't have to write the whole code for me because I know I don't have much, but if someone could just point me in the right direction/give me a hint as to how to proceed it'd be very helpful.

```
data_file = open("data.txt", "r")

total = 0 
for line_str in data_file:  
    line_str = line_str.strip()
    total+=1
```

Comment: You can use the standard `csv` module to read the text file.

Comment: This smells a lot like you're asking us to do your homework. If so, you should check with your professor if this represents an academic integrity issue.

Comment: @coderanger I'm not. I literally said don't write the code out for me. I just wanted a point in the right direction...

Answer (score 2):

The method you need is [`str's split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). The takes a string, like a line in a file, and breaks it up in to multiple chunks. After that you'll also need to use `float()` to parse the floating point number from the string chunk.

Comment: How do i make sure I only split the numbers though? That is my major dilemma

Comment: @NouraAsrar what have you tried so far? Have you tried running `.split()` on the line and seeing what you get? This is python, you can easily fire up a repl and experiment!

Comment: You don't, you split the whole line in to a list and then pull out the 3rd item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

With [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) library the solution is simple:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
df['BMI'] = df['Weight(kg)'] / (df['Height(m)']**2)
df.describe()
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use this method

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by this way:

```
data_file = open("data.txt", "r")`

total = 0

for line_str in data_file:      
         [float(s) for s in line_str.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

Comment: This is neither valid Python code (because of the rouge backtick) nor accomplishing anything :)